# Invalid Operation Exception was unhandled

Tags: wpf

got this error `Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.`

this error is found in this line:

`BuildstreamComboBox.ItemsSource = dz;`

the code:

```
    public void PopulatebuildstreamFromXMLFile()
    {
        if (BuildmachineComboBox.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            ds3.Clear();
            ds3.ReadXml(@"C:\GUI\buildermanageremail.xml");

            DataView dy = ds3.Tables["buildstream4"].DefaultView;

            BuildstreamComboBox.ItemsSource = dy; //Sets the collection of items from which to populate
            BuildstreamComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "value"; //Sets the path within an item to use for display
        }
        if (BuildmachineComboBox.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            ds3.Clear();
            ds3.ReadXml(@"C:\GUI\buildermanageremail.xml");

            DataView dz = ds3.Tables["buildstream5"].DefaultView;

            BuildstreamComboBox.ItemsSource = dz; //Sets the collection of items from which to populate
            BuildstreamComboBox.DisplayMemberPath = "value"; //Sets the path within an item to use for display
        }
    }
```

where `ds3` is definded:

`DataSet ds3 = new DataSet();`

anybody has any idea?

Comment: How does your BuildstreamComboBox look in XAML? Does it have child elements?

Comment: oh yes.. it does have the previous item source. forgot to remove them thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 0):

Your question itself contains your answer, you need to clear the items collection prior of assigning it a new items source lke this - `BuildstreamComboBox.Items.Clear()`